# When we pass an array to a function, how does the copy work?

Tags: c, arrays, function, pass-by-reference

I read in the K&R C book that when we pass an array to a function, the address of the array (a pointer containing the address of the first element of the array) is passed to the function, therefore making it seem like a pass-by-reference (although there is no such real mechanism in C)

However, the below doesn't make sense to me then -

```
void test(char arr[10]) {
    arr[2] = 'a';
 }

 main() {
     char arr[5] = "hello";
     test(arr);
     printf("%s", arr);
     return 0;
 }
```

This gives me healo as expected.

But does that mean that this is how this is evaluated?

The "char arr[]" argument getting assigned the pointer to the actual array? How does that work?

```
char arr[10] = &arr[0]
```

doesn't make sense to me!

Comment: I don't see a contradiction. *"making it seem like a pass-by-reference"* - meaning that you *can* modify it and have the result visible outside the function.

Comment: Yes a a copy of the address of the array is given as parameter. Yes, via this address, you do change the original array. What is unclear?

Comment: arrays decay to pointers in may situations and one of it is when passing it to a function, so `test(arr);` is basicly the same as `test(&arr[0]);`.

Comment: What I am confused about is this: I've always thought of it this way - that when we pass arguments to a function, the function's parameter in its definition and the actual argument while calling a function get equated. So when we say that we have `char arr[]` in the func definition but pass `&arr[0]`, I am unable to understand how those two get equated

Comment: It is a special case for functions. When you specify an array as a function parameter, the C language treats the parameter as a pointer type, not an array type.

Comment: @user3655977 you give an array in argument, in that case its address is given, it is not copied

Comment: Bruno, my confusion is regarding how we actually equate the array defined in the function signature and the address that is passed from the function call. They two seem to be incompatible. @jxh is I think understanding what my confusion is

Comment: @user3655977 `void test(char arr[])` and `void test(char *arr);` is the same, there is no difference.

Comment: Even if I defined it as `void test(char arr[10])`, would it still ignore the 10 and consider it as just a char pointer? Wouldn't that mean loss of information (the value 10)? @Osiris

Comment: @user3655977 Yes `arr` is then still of type `char *`. Giving dimensions to an array parameter does only make sense in the multi dimensional case.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot @Osiris

Comment: user3655977 Re: [unable to understand how those two get equated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54098883/when-we-pass-an-array-to-a-function-how-does-the-copy-work#comment95030602_54098883).  Think of it as 3 things.  The argument  given `main_arr` of type `int [10]`, the converted argument passed `&main_arr[0]` of type `char *` and the parameter received `char test_arr[10]` of type `char *`.

Answer (score 0):

in *test* the parameter *arr* receive the address of the argument because it is an array, not a copy, so you modify the value of the *arr* in *main* (it was more practical to not use the same name in *test* and *main* :-) )

*void test(char arr[])* and *void test(int * arr)* are two ways to write the same thing

to call *test(arr)* and *test(&arr[0])* are also two ways to write the same thing

Comment: my confusion is regarding how we actually equate the array defined in the function signature and the address that is passed from the function call. They two seem to be incompatible

Comment: @user3655977 you can replace the signature by _void test(char * arr)_ and you will have exactly the same definition

Comment: Apologies if I am being a bit thick. Can you explain that when we pass an argument in a function call, how is it equated to the function parameter in its signature? Just like a direct assignment, right? But in this case, how would the `char arr[]` get equated to the `&arr[0]` address that we are passing?

Comment: to have the type `char[]` or `char *` is equivalent for the parameter, is just 2 ways to write the same thing. And to call test with _arr_ or _&arr[0]_ is also exactly the same thing, just two ways to write the same thing

Comment: @bruno Even if I defined it as void test(char arr[10]), would it still ignore the 10 and consider it as just a char pointer? Wouldn't that mean loss of information (the value 10)?

Comment: @user3655977 If you do that in C unfortunately you will not have even a warning, in C++ it is an error.

Comment: @user3655977 using the dimension 10 the compiler will consider the size is 10 in _test_, but if you use an index greater than 5 you go out of the vector into the stack This is why I never use C but C++, independently of the advantage of the class etc of course, it is more secure at compile time